# Remove the reappearing of subtitle from previous video played

Tags: jquery, video

I am trying to dynamically allocate the link for video and subtitle through jQuery. But when I play a video the subtitle of previous video comes along with new video subtitle.

html code:

```
<video   controls   oncontextmenu="return false;" id="video" class="video"  >
                     <source src="#" type="video/mp4" id="abc"/>
                     <track  src="#" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-us" id="zxc">
                     Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                  </video>
```

jQuery:

```
$.get(c+'/count.txt', function(data) {

                 for(var i=1;i<=data;i++){
                    $('#myTable').append('<tr ><td class="abc" id="link'+i+'">Episode '+i+'<i class="fa fa-play right "></i></td></tr>');
                              }
               for(var j=1;j<=data;j++){
                   var id="#link"+j;

                    $(id).click(function(){


                      var cdo=$(this).text();

                        if(cdo.length==9){
                         var pp=cdo[0]+cdo[1]+"0"+cdo[8];
                           $("#epod").text(pp);
                        }

                        else{
                          var pp=cdo[0]+cdo[1]+cdo[8]+cdo[9];
                           $("#epod").text(pp);
                        }

                        var sg=$("#sr").text()+"/"+$("#son").text()+"/"+$(this).text()+".mp4";
                        var sb=$("#sr").text()+"/"+$("#son").text()+"/"+$(this).text()+".vtt";

                        $('#video').get(0).pause();
                        $('#abc').attr('src',sg);

                        $('#zxc').attr('src',sb);
                        $('#video').get(0).load();
                        $('#video').get(0).play();                     

                  });
                }
```

Screenshots: [First video played](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSas.png) - [Second video played with subtiles of previous ones too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJtY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem will solved if you try creating video dinamically

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Be06DChtVMpx10a6K2b4?p=preview)

Html Code:

```
<div id="video-box"></div>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
```

Js Code:

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  var video1 = 'https://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/video/sintel-short.mp4',
    video2 = 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
    track1 = 'track1.vtt',
    track2 = 'track2.vtt';

  playVideo('video-box', video1, track1); 

  $('#first').on('click', function(){
    playVideo('video-box', video1, track1);
  });

  $('#second').on('click', function(){
     playVideo('video-box', video2, track2);
  });


  function playVideo(wrapperId, src, trackSrc) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById(wrapperId);

    $('#video').remove();

    var video = document.createElement("video");
    video.id = "video";
    video.controls = "controls";
    video.class = "video";

    var source = document.createElement("source");
    source.src = src;
    source.type = "video/mp4";
    source.id = "abc";

    console.log(video, source, wrapper)

    video.appendChild(source);
    wrapper.appendChild(video);

    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {    
      var track = document.createElement("track"); 
        track.kind = "captions"; 
        track.label = "English"; 
        track.default = "default";
        track.srclang = "en"; 
        track.src = trackSrc; 
        this.appendChild(track); 
    });

    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
});
```